# Docker build failed to load metadata

Tags: docker, http, docker-build

I am trying to run `docker build` and constantly get this error:

```
ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.(bla-bla...)

failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to do request: Head https://docker.(bla-bla...) Service Unavailable
```

The problem is the service is available only through http and I don't understand why docker decides to get it via https.

My colleagues with older version of docker do not have this problem, and they did not have to do any additional settings.

What can be done to solve the problem? And does it really has anything to do with http/https issue, or is it something else?

Comment: I can confirm this issue with Docker for Windows v20.10.2

Comment: It appears we have found a possible workaround: docker pull the base image(s) of your Dockerfile before executing docker build. And of course you need to define the source registry as insecure in your docker engine, if it requires http.

Answer (score 0):

Faced with the same issue. Looks like it is a temporary issue from their side or your DNS/VPN.

try to download it locally using `docker pull`, in my case it helps (partially). I just trying to pull the required image every few seconds during 30 secs and ... it pulled. So my recommendation is - do not waste your time thinking the issue is somewhere in your code :) just try to wait ...

[image]